# Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub. (Insomnia + Codespaces)

Tags: rest, github, insomnia, codespaces

I've been doing some tests with NodeJS from GitHub Codespaces. When I use Insomnia REST (I put the open port link from Codespaces) everything appears fine, I log in to GitHub from insomnia but when I do that, I get the following screen.
[Insomnia REST cookie login problem with GitHub Codespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aIRY.png)
I have searched how to modify the cookies access, but I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I would really appreciate your help, please :'c

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct?  This is what I'd expect to see if you tried to access `github.com` instead of `api.github.com`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.